# Как вернуть объект в переменную из async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, асинхронность

Всем спасибо, ответ на вопрос чуть ниже, вероятно это сэкономит время.

**Никак. Вообще никак. Нет. Нельзя синхронно дождаться асинхронного вызова. Точно нельзя. И даже так нельзя.**

Из асинхронной функции вернется промис! Объект можно разобрать в пределах async функции.

---

Подскажите возможно ли из async вернуть объект в переменную а не промис.

Await работает в пределах async syntax, если помещать `const json = await getData(url);` в async логично что опять будет возвращен промис.

```js
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

const getData = async (url) => {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const jsonObj = await response.json();

    return jsonObj;
        
}


const json = getData(url);
alert(getData(url));
```

Comment: Никак. Вообще никак. Нет. Нельзя синхронно дождаться асинхронного вызова. Точно нельзя. И даже так нельзя.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну почему же никак вообще никак?)  Может быть у нас разночтения, но.....вот у меня есть класс, в котором есть свойство `data`, в одном методе я запрашиваю данные и складирую результат в это свойство, а потом, к примеру при клике на кнопку какую-либо, я обрабатываю данные в другом методе, беря данные из `data` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это не синхронно. Если буквально читать вопрос, то автор хочет получить из **async**-фунции объект, а не промис. Что невозможно потому что **async** по определению возвращает промиc.

Comment: Все такие умные я в а.уе, минусуют сразу, предлагают закрыть вопрос, объяснить никто не попытался сразу начали заваливать, классика жанра

Comment: Ну извините, но в описании минуса написано «Вопрос … не несёт пользы». Ваш вопрос именно такой, потому что это вопрос тут задают каждый день.

Comment: @AlexeyTen собственно с самого начала на мысль и навело что вероятно это в какой-то степени даже тупо, решил спросить.

Comment: @AlexeyTen если в таком ключе, то да. получить чистое значение из async нельзя......но всё же суть автора чуть более широкая. Он хочет оперировать данными дальше. Вот основная суть я думаю.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на эту суть в дубликате есть ответы

Comment: @AlexeyTen кстати нет. И я планирую туда дописать ответ наверное...... потому что уже сотый раз вижу, как люди, которые даже применяют async/await  пытаются сделать функцию асинхронной, а потом вне её пытаются делать console.log или то, что автор..... то есть суть сводится к тому, что я описал в первом комментарии..... условно: вызывать асинхронщину, дождаться ответа, сложить её в переменную, а потом, когда-нибудь, не обязательно сразу, а может через N операций, воспользоваться данными из этой переменной......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = 'https://www.binance.me/api/v3/ticker/price?symbols=%5B%22BTCUSDT%22,%22ETHUSDT%22,%22LTCUSDT%22,%22DOGEUSDT%22,%22TRXUSDT%22%5D';

const getData = async (url) => {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const jsonObj = await response.json();

    return jsonObj;
        
}


const json = getData(url);
getData(url).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

---

или так

```js
var url = 'https://www.binance.me/api/v3/ticker/price?symbols=%5B%22BTCUSDT%22,%22ETHUSDT%22,%22LTCUSDT%22,%22DOGEUSDT%22,%22TRXUSDT%22%5D';

const getData = async (url) => {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const jsonObj = await response.json();

    return jsonObj;
        
}



(async function() {
  let response = await getData(url);
  console.log(response);
})()
```

Comment: getData(url).then(response => {console.log(response);});  это и так понятно что внутри функции я получу массив, как вернуть в новую переменную объект из асинхронной функции что бы потом с ним работать дальше. Или это не возможно?

Comment: ты итак получаешь данные в новую переменную и работаешь с ней дальше. что не так?))  второй пример смотри............ нужно понимать как именно ты хочешь с ней работать....не вижу пока никаких проблем во втором примере. ..........."Или это не возможно?" --- всё вполне возможно

Comment: мне нужно вытащить объект с ценами, потом их передать в график, там тоже объект, и в параметр value объекта графика нужно передать параметры price из async объекта, как-то так

Comment: конечно удобнее было бы просто сохранить объект с ценами в отдельной переменной, и потом по  ключам массива передать их в график и построить кривую, а сейчас получатся при обращении к переменной я получаю промис а там уже сам объект

Comment: Честно говоря проблема не ясна. Например чем не устраивает второй вариант в ответе? Не знаю как у вас там, но условно можно иметь три метода: `getData`, `renderChartByIds` и `showChart`. Все они будут `async`. К примеру метод с именем `showChart` вызвается при клике на кнопку (показать график). Он в себе последовательно вызовет `getData`, положит данные в переменную, отфильтруешь данные как нужно и потом вызовет метод `renderChartByIds` с передачей отфитрованных данных.....

Comment: ну типо да ) придется так и делать, все методы async и там уже внутри копаться.

Comment: да, но ведь по-другому и смысла нет делать. всё равно происходит какая-то операция. А операция - можно назвать функция или метод. вне функций уже мало что пишут...разве что hello world. А при асинке уже можно выделить несколько операций.