# Как записать данные из трех асинхронных запросов в три разные переменные и потом отправить их дальше в другой функционал?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch, promise, callback

Здравствуйте товарищи!

Есть три переменные

`let person1, person2, person3;`

А также есть три запроса на **/people/1, people/2, people/3**, окончательный результат которых мы присваиваем одной из переменных выше соответственно

```
fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1', {
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    person1 = res;
  });
```

Далее нужно три новых переменных передать в функцию goFurther

```
function goFurther(person1, person2, person3) {
  console.log(person1, person2, person3);
}
```

Не могу понять как справиться с этой задачей без setTimeout.

Пытаюсь решить данную задачку с помощью Promise или async, await - однако никак не могу разобраться.

Пожалуйста помогите конкретно с этим примером! Аналогия от решения сильно поможет мне разобраться. Также не могу понять как здесь применить callback схему.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431113/#comment2551618_1431115   вот практически то, что тебе надо

Comment: А ещё вам может понадобиться [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кстати, запрос можно вынести как отдельную функцию, чтобы 3 раза не дублировать код:

```js
const logPersons = (person1, person2, person3) => {
  console.log('person1', person1);
  console.log('person2', person2);
  console.log('person3', person3);
}

const getPerson = async(personId) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${personId}`);

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();

      return data;
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

const getPersons = async() => {
  let [
    person1,
    person2,
    person3
  ] = await Promise.allSettled([
    getPerson(1),
    getPerson(2),
    getPerson(3)
  ]);

  logPersons(person1, person2, person3);
}

getPersons();
```

Comment: В `if (response.ok)` явно не хватает случая `else`

Comment: И getPerson(n) будут выполнятся последовательно, что может быть не очень хорошо.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Сам сказал и сам же не использовал :) Спасибо за замечания!

Comment: @EzioMercer - благодарю - все сработало как полагается. +100 вам в карму